# Wheel Color Picker jquery modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I want to use this plugin in my website https://github.com/fujaru/jquery-wheelcolorpicker/

by default , when we initiate the plugin with

```
<input type="text" data-wheelcolorpicker="" data-wcp-layout="block">
```

it will look like this

[image: Default UI]

so i try to make the UI look like this

[image: My Design]

Any idea how to do it? , in my understanding it needed some modification on the plugin js file, can you guys help me with this , or maybe find another way how to do it , thanks

Comment: To change the look of the plugin you'd need to rewrite it - or find one that matches your requirements exactly.

Comment: @rorymccrossan any similar tool suggestion ? , i think it will take to much time to modifiy the wheelcolorpicker.js

Answer (score 1):

Not a round, but it have all the functionnality you want:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Hexagon-Color-Picker-Plugin-with-jQuery-jQuery-UI.html

Also, a tuto to do your own wheel from scratch:
https://dzone.com/articles/creating-your-own-html5